# Getting invalid typescript errors in valid TS code

Tags: reactjs, typescript, compiler-errors, create-react-app, tsconfig

I am having a create-react-app (v17.0.2) with typescript (v4.5.5). I am getting typescript errors even in valid TS code. The same was working earlier, I opened this project after about 5-6 months and started getting these errors. I am pretty sure this has something to do with tsconfig/version of some package/ node version, etc. but I am unable to figure it out.

The below snippet is taken straight out of official [ts docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html) but still getting error:
[image: sample code]

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please post your tsconfig file in text form so that others can try to reproduce the issue. You should also add your actual code and the error that you're getting.

Comment: @RyanPattillo oops! I had added the sample code, but it got deleted while formatting the question. Have fixed that.

Comment: I added the code from the screenshot and your tsconfig file to the [TypeScript ESLint Playground](https://typescript-eslint.io/play/) and I'm not seeing an error. Can you post your entire code and/or reproduce the error using that playground link?